# Broken iPhone 6 can't connect to iTunes

Tags: iphone, itunes

My iPhone broke the other day and the screen is broken so bad it doesn't work anymore. It has typed its own passcode on the lock screen so many times it has disabled the phone so now I can't do anything with it.

The lock screen says "Connect to iTunes," but when I try to connect it says that I have to enter the phone's passcode which I can't.

What can I do to back up my phone or connect it to iTunes? If I go to an Apple store, will they replace it or change the phone all together?

Comment: Did you already have iCloud backups turned on before the screen was smashed?  If so, it should already be backed-up.  As for the replacement, no.  Apple doesn't replace iPhones (or any device, really) for screens that were broken by the owner.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the digitizer (the part that recognizes your touches) is also broken. My experience with Apple store is they will try to replace your screen first (at a cost).

Many third party repair shops can help you get a working digitizer connected without erasing the device. Expect to pay them extra for the data transfer as part of the repair. You could even just pay them for the data transfer and then go back to Apple for a repair that has warranty from the manufacturer.